# What is Offset in the Box Model?

Tags: html

I have seen many explanations of the html Box Model, but I have not found an explanation of what the "Offset" is.  It is visible in the Layout Tab of FireBug, Dev Tools etc.

Could someone give an explanation of this?

Comment: Where did you see that offset ?

Comment: IE F12 Developer Tools, Firefox etc, under the "Layout" tab.

Comment: Oh, then it's not really part of the box model, it' the resulting relative position of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset is the x,y coordinates of the element calculated by the browser.